# RADEON HD 7670m drivers installation in 20.04 LTS

Tags: drivers, graphics, xorg, radeon, amd-graphics

This GPU is not detected for proprietray drivers installation in Softwares & Update section.

AMD has given the drivers only for 14.04.5 LTS and depends on xorg version of that time 1.1x also Linux kernel 4.4

Is there a way to rollback to that xorg version & use the same driver on 20.04 installation.

A guide would be of great help..

Currently im using the iGPU Intel HD Graphics 4000 MESA GT2..//
Radeon 7670m is shown & is inactive. i solved screen tearing with intel.conf file in xorg.

I am also ok with using 14.04.6 LTS now without support, But a guide for setting all ppas or apt repo for getting most recent softwares with dependency restrictions..would be of great help.

Comment: Run `DRI_PRIME=1 glxinfo | grep OpenGL` and you'll see that all is working. You don't need any drivers.

Comment: Now AMD drivers are integrated into the kernel and work quite well.

Comment: I have intel.conf for xorg screen tearing set up , i would like to switch to radeon , by updating grub  im not 100% sure about a working tutorial..

Comment: You can't "switch to radeon". You can run any application you like with radeon using `DRI_PRIME=1`.

Comment: I hope adding DRI_PRIME=1 in /etc/environment & restarting wont cause a conflict with xorg and intel conf.

Comment: Why are you worried about intel.conf? It is unrelated.

Comment: I have set intel.conf file for xorg to resolve screen tearing.  previously using a radeon.conf stopped system from booting and i was into root terminal. To login. .. i guess i need to blacklist intel graphics and set radeon=1 some where in etc and change to radeon.conf for xorg config. Note running DRI_Prime = 1 is still iGPU in my case i guesss

Comment: No, you don't need to blacklist anything. `DRI_Prime` != `DRI_PRIME`. And why would you want to run everuthing on radeon? You are doing weird things.

Comment: I deleted 20-intel.conf file in xorg.conf.d and screen tearing is back again,  this time i am able to see AMD device with DRI_PRIME=1 . is there a solution to solve screen tearing and set default DRI_PRIME=1 some where? i hope this is my final Q reg this topic.

Comment: So ask a new question regarding tearing on dual graphics or find an existing answer.